# SVN Comparing next line differently

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn, newline, git-svn

I have SVP Repo and FTP production. Some time I have to edit directly through FTP with client.
When I downloaded the updated files from FTP to local to compare the changes with SVN version I found it has changes to the NEXT LINE characters (CRLF & LF). And this caused the folders and files detected differently even though I did not update a single character inside the files.

Can any one suggest how to solve this problem either through SVN setting, FTP setting or a tools to replace back the NEXT LINE characters.

[image: Downloaded from FT having different characters for next line that caused SVN client detect it has changes]

Thanks

sdfds

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to set the ftp to binary mode. How exactly to do that will depend on your FTP application, but the command that needs to be sent is just "binary". Presumably your ftp server defaults to ascii or autodetects ascii.

Comment: I have no idea how to set this in CPanel linux!

Comment: That's the name of your ftp client?